# Extend a WPF control in another assembly in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

i am using DevExpress and i'm creating and extended TextEdit.

When i extend from a normal TextBox it's all ok. Behind the code i use simply:

```
public partial class AutocompleteTextBox : TextBox
```

And in XAML i start with:

```
<TextBox x:Class="...">
```

And all is fine. Now i want change the base class from TextBox to the DevExpress's EditText control. So i changed the class in code to inherit from the TextEdit istead of TextBox but in XAML it give me the error that **partial class must have the same base class**. The problem is that i don't know what to do. If i use:

```
<DevExpress.Xtra.Editors.TextEdit x:Class="...">
```

it give me error.

What i need to do?

Comment: change `public partial class AutocompleteTextBox : TextBox` to `public partial class AutocompleteTextBox : TextEdit`

Comment: "extended `TextEdit`" - What exactly are you trying to do? the DevExpress WPF TextEdit is already very customizable and has lots of features, and subclassing WPF UI elements is discouraged unless you have a `strong` reason to. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MareInfinitus as i said, i changed the code, the problem is in the XAML.

Comment: @HighCore i'm creating an autocomplete textbox. Because i have not find something good online. It's almost complete and it works good. But i don't know why DevExpress give different color theme to TextBox and TextEdit, so i want simply change the base class.

Comment: @MauroValvano use `DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.Lookup.LookupEdit` instead, which already has built-in autocomplete functionality. BTW, `DevExpress.Xtra` namespace has winforms-related stuff, don't use it.

Comment: From the code in your example: TextEdit baseclass in XAML, TextBox baseclass in codebehind. Please show more code or at least the code that gives the error AND the error message.